# Xcode - TableViewController not showing large title in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a TableViewController embedded within a NavigationController.

Selecting Prefer Large Titles does not update the storyboard but if I run the app I see the large title on the table view as expected.

My expectation from what I understand is that the storyboard should also update.

Is there a step that I have missed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in the view controller:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```